# Describe parameters of two methods with the same parameters in the XML documentation c#

Tags: c#, xml-documentation

I am sure there must be a way to do this, but maybe I don't know how to phrase the question.

I have something like the code below.  In the method summary for `Method2`, how do I refer to the long description for the parameter that I have typed in for `Method1`?  Without doing a copy-and-paste.

```
/// <summary>
/// This method does something.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="parameter1">The first parameter Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna</param>
public void Method1(string parameter1) { }

/// <summary>
/// This method does something else.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="parameter1">The first parameter Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna</param>
public void Method2(string parameter1) { }
```

Comment: cref attribute might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't think there is any tags that will automatically *copy* the documentation from one method onto another. You *can* use `<cref...>` to make links but I would try to minimize the number of links because if you use this all over the place, when I ask for documentation for method X I will have to navigate to method Y, then some of those parameters are documented on method Z and K, which has some of its documentation in method L. Soon I have forgotten which method I was trying to find to begin with.